# Cmd String to PAnsiChar in delphi

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-7

I am relatively new to Delphi and I want to make a quick application the uses the `ShellExecute` command.

I want to use string values in edit boxes to add to the command line for doing the processing job outside of the application.

Everything works fine, but I get the error :

> "Incompatible types: String and PAnsiChar"

I have tried to convert it using:
`Variable := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(editbox.Text)`, but to no avail.

Can anyone assist me with this problem please.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using Delphi 7 and not XE7? While Delphi 7 has 8-bit string type compatible with `PAnsiChar`, Delphi XE7 has 16-bit string type that is compatible with `PChar`.

Comment: I am using Delphi 7 (2002)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Delphi 7, it's a simple typecast to `PChar`, which is already a `PAnsiChar`:

```
PChar(YourStringVariable);
```

or

```
PChar('Some text here');  // Cast not needed; demonstration only
PChar('C:\' + AFileName); // Cast needed because of variable use
```

Using it with `ShellExecute`:

```
AFile := 'C:\MyDir\Readme.txt';
Res :=   ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(AFile),
                      nil, nil, SW_NORMAL )
```

Comment: There's no need to cast a literal and I'd argue that it's better not to

Comment: @David: I don't see any harm in doing so, as the API call clearly asks for a PChar, and the cast makes it clear that you're passing one. It also avoids later issues for new programmers, who don't understand why `'open'` works, but `'C:\ADir\' + AFileName` won't. Edited to clarify and show the difference, though. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any harm either. I personally think it's clearer to avoid casts where possible.

Comment: Unless you really need the verb 'open' it is usually better to just pass nil instead. This will use the default verb for the file type. Not every file type supports the verb 'open'.

Comment: Thank you Ken White. The problem still isn't resolved. I keep getting the error.

Comment: @maddog550: I can't help you with that, because you're a) not providing the actual code you're using, and b) you're not giving us the error message in a context that relates to that code. If you want help, [edit] your question to provide the **exact code** (including variable declarations) that is causing the problem, the **exact error message you're seeing** (includinig identifying which line is causing it). We can only help based on the information you provide, which is what we've done. You want more help? Provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

How could it work fine when you cannot compile it?

You have posted too little code to be sure what is wrong, but you definitively have one typecast too much. `AnsiChar` is type that can store only single character and it makes no sense here.

If `Variable` is `PAnsiChar` then you should be using:

```
Variable := PAnsiChar(editbox.Text)
```

Comment: That was my mistake sorry. I did try your method but I keep getting the error.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more code. What type is `Variable` and how do you call `ShellExecute`